# equivalent syntax for 'for loop' & 'while loop'?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I know basic examples about *foreach* to *for loop* and **while loop** since I was begin coding I didn't paying attention from the speed of executing a script which it is **very very important** since then I keep converting all my *for each* statement to *for loop*. If it's comes to `array` i'm quite confused -_-. I know it gives me down vote posting this. LIKE **I'd rather let people figure things out for myself.**
I just need a bit of guide using a for loop statement. How can I convert the following foreach loop to for loop/ while loop statement?

like what I seen on phpbenchmark.com as

> $i = 0; while($i < 1000000) ++$i;
>
> for($i = 0; $i < 1000000; ++$i);

CODE:

```
<?php
$user['001'] = 'A';
$user['002'] = 'B';
$user['003'] = 'C';
$user['004'] = 'D';

foreach($user as $id => $name)
{
    echo '<br>Id='.$id.'Name='.$name;
}
?>
```

thanks alot.

EXPECTED OUTPUT LIKE foreach output:

```
Id=001Name=A  
Id=002Name=B  
Id=003Name=C  
Id=004Name=D
```

also what if I have an array keys like

> ```
> $user['AAA'] = 'A';
> $user['BBB'] = 'B';
> $user['CCC'] = 'C';
> $user['DDD'] = 'D';
> ```

it will output as:

> ```
> Id=AAAName=A  
> Id=AAAName=B  
> Id=AAAName=C  
> Id=AAAName=D
> ```

Comment: are you asking how to iterate through an array with a for loop?

Comment: I think you're asking how to iterate over the array using a `while` loop with a simple integer $I when your array keys have numbers with leading zeroes..... DON'T MICRO-OPTIMIZE.

Comment: Why do you think `foreach` is a performance problem to begin with? Have you tested it?

Comment: @deceze yes I tested it like 200 micro time faster than foreach loop

Comment: Use the appropriate loop for what you're doing: that's why PHP provides those options - otherwise you're simply teaching yourself to make code that is harder to read and subsequently harder to maintain

Comment: If "200 micro time" is a significant and important improvement for you, PHP is the wrong language to begin with. The problem is though that this improvement may work for arrays with integer keys, but is probably not reproducible with other kinds of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` and `while` loops you show are simply incrementing a number, which you can use to access elements of an array if the keys of that array are equivalent to those numbers. In other words, `for` or `while` loops have nothing to do with arrays as such, you're just using a number as a key to an array.

If your array keys are not simple continuous integers, this is more problematic. You could try to construct the correct keys from your `$i` variable, but why? You should just iterate explicitly over the keys of the array, for which `foreach` is perfect. You *can* also do it with [`each`](http://php.net/each) or any number of other complicated ways:

```
while (list($key, $value) = each($array)) {
   ...
}
```

But I doubt it's going to be significantly faster than a `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

do you wanted something like this?

```
$length = count($user);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
   print $user[$i];
}
```

EDIT: or something like this?

```
$user = array ( '001' => 'A',
              '002' => 'B',
              '033' => 'C' );
while( list ( $id, $name) = each ( $user) )
{
   echo '<br>Id=' .$id. 'Name='.$name;
}
```

EDIT:also works with you r AAA = A etc case

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
<?php
$user['001'] = 'A';
$user['002'] = 'B';
$user['003'] = 'C';
$user['004'] = 'D';

while (current($user)) {

        echo '<br>Id='.key($user).'Name='.$user[key($user)];
        next($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$user['001'] = 'A';
$user['002'] = 'B';
$user['003'] = 'C';
$user['004'] = 'D';
$keys = array_keys($user);
$length = sizeof($user);
for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
    echo 'id: '.$keys[$i].' value: '.$user[$keys[$i]].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: This loops through the array once to extract the keys, allocates additional memory to store these keys, then loops through the key array again. Is this really *still* faster? Will it still be faster with *really large arrays*?

Comment: For a guy that wants to micro-optimize their loops, I find it strange that the accepted answer has the `sizeof()` in the `for` criteria.... clearly they don't yet know enough about micro-optimization to know that is an overhead in every iteration of the loop

Comment: @deceze it will just allocate extra memory for the keys, the loop process would still be faster. Mr. Baker, thanks for pointing out. Would you please elaborate your it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The time that may hypothetically be saved in the loop is probably offset by the call to `array_keys` is what I'm saying. And Mark is saying that `sizeof($user)` is called every iteration, which takes time as well. You only need to call it once: `for ($i = 0, $size = sizeof($user); $i < $size; $i++) ...`

Comment: I don't think that would cause an overhead. Anyway, you could try allocating the size of array to a variable and then use that variable in the loop. This would solve that issue as well. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: It is an overhead, because it's an extra function call (calling the sizeof() function) every iteration to retrieve a value that won't change from one iteration to the next; that's why a one-off call before the loop to store the value in a variable is better